# loadHTMLFile not working on redirect pages

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler

I have been experimenting with `loadHTMLfile`. It works well for the most part, but fails in many cases. I was wondering if there is some work around for the following problem.

A lot of times, `loadHTMLfile` will fail if, for example the URL fed to the function, is: `www.somedomain.com` and when such a URL is typed in to a browsers address bar, it redirects to `www.somedomain.com/page/default.asp` before it renders.

How do webcrawlers overcome this problem? Is there a way to use some PHP function, like `loadHTMLfile` to load the HTML file of the document that is rendered after the request to the server is made and all redirects take place? (essentially simulate a user visiting the URL via any browsers address bar)

I appreciate any advice, thanks in advance!

Comment: _How do webcrawlers overcome this problem?_ - They aren't using PHP

Answer (score 1):

```
//without following redirects
$ch = curl_init('http://google.com');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip, deflate'
));
$content = curl_exec($ch);
echo $content;

//with following redirects
$ch = curl_init('http://google.com');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip, deflate',
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
));
$content = curl_exec($ch);
echo $content;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @cetver. Can you please show a basic example using any domain i.e. `somedomain.com` to grab the html content after the redirect, using your code snippet? I appreciate the help!

Comment: Thank you! Can you please clarify the purpose of these two lines: `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip, deflate',`

Comment: All information you can find here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php